# Java regular expression to replace the string from the xml string

Tags: java, regex

I am having string as below and i need to replace the value of ref as like in the output.

```
Input String:
 <sheet type="xl"><dimension ref="A1:W101"/></sheet>

Output String:
 <sheet type="xl"><dimension ref="A1:j202"/></sheet>
```

I have tried using the **(?<=\b(ref=)).*(?=/>)** , but it was matching till the end of the string.

Can anyone help me, how can I use the regular expression to replace the ref value like the output string.

Comment: `(?<=\b(ref=)).*?(?=/>)`

Comment: Use an XML parser

Comment: is the input ref always the same?

Comment: I hope you understand that parsing XML is like parsing HTML: regular expressions **can** not work for arbitrary input. So unless you have **super** tight control over your input, you are better of using a **parser** instead of regular expressions.

Comment: (?<=\b(ref=)).*?(?=/>) this solved my problem.

Comment: @SooryaPrakash remember that a forum works because answer guys answers some asker guys, and asker guys accept answers from the first ones ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex this way :

```
String str = "<sheet type=\"xl\"><dimension ref=\"A1:W101\"/></sheet>";
String replaceBy = "A1:j202";

str = str.replaceAll("(ref=\")(.*)(\")", "$1" + replaceBy + "$3");
System.out.println(str);
```

This will also work :

`str = str.replaceAll("(?<=\\b(ref=)).*?(?=/>)", "\"" + replaceBy + "\"");`